# Gate hinge position/location

Tags: cabinets, hinges, hardware, gates

Which side of this cabinet/gate hinge should go on the cabinet door? I believe the long-side.

https://www.natman.com/detail/841-ornamental-reversible-t-hinges-n881-904

[image]

Further, should the hinge pin be located right over the space where the sides meet the cabinet door? I designed in a 1/8th inch gap around the door to prevent rubbing.

Sorry if these are basic questions, I've only got one shot at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long side of the hinge needs to be fixed to your cabinet door, align the hinge pin flush with the end of the door like the picture below

[image]

Make sure hinge faces the side you want the door to open to.